# Using Invitable Friends API and Taggable friends API to retrieve more information

Tags: facebook-graph-api

What does Invitable Friends API  and Taggable Friends API return?
Do they return all the friends (both users and non-users of my app) of a user?
If it returns all users, Can I use these APIs to retrieve other detailed information of the friends like Birthdays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They return all users, but you only get an invite or tagging token and the name, nothing else. You can only retrieve the birthday of a friend if that friend has authorized your App with the `user_birthday` permission. Else, that permission would not make any sense ;)

Remember, the Invitable Friends API is for inviting friends to a game with Canvas implementation only - and the Taggable Friends API is for tagging friends only.

Comment: Is there any way to retrieve birthday of all the friends (both users and non-users of my app) using graph API(v2.2 or above)?Please suggest if any workaround can be done using any other APIs

Comment: no, there is no way and there is no workaround. birthdays of friends who did not authorize your app with the user_birthday permission are none of your business. as you can read in my answer, that permission would not make any sense if you could just grab the data without permission.